# Ошибка "Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine"

Tags: php, mysql

Доброй ночи.
Во время добавления записи в таблицу происходит следующая ошибка:

> "Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine"

В чем причина?)
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы в запросе пытаетесь в поле со свойством auto-increment  вставить невозможное значение.
Напишите лучше код того где возникает ошибка

Comment: Спасибо.
Но я уже исправил эту ошибку. Необходимо было обновить MySQl сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Измените тип поля с autoincrement на INT или BIGINT